# 'SearchIcon' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have tried to display a search icon inside my search bar, but it isn't working. my code  is

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

//31915c5e

const API_URL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com?apikey = 31915c5e'

const App = () => {
 
    const searchMovies = async (title) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
        const data = await response.json();

        console.log(data.search); 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        searchMovies('spiderman');
    }, []);



    return (
        <div className="app">
            <h1>MovieLand</h1>

            <div className="search">
                <input
                    placeholder="search for movies"
                />

            /*https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=gi*/
                <img
                    src={SearchIcon}
                    alt="search"
                    
                />

            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

showing a search icon inside my search bar.
on the browser it displays 'SearchIcon' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Where is `SearchIcon` defined ?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this, I would either install @fortawesome/react-fontawesome and @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons and do it with that, or, the option I would prefer that consists in using inline styles, positioning the icon as a background of the input tag; it would be something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import searchIcon from "path/to/search-icon.svg";

function SearchInput() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
        style={{
          padding: "0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 2rem",
          background: `url(${searchIcon}) no-repeat`,
          backgroundSize: "1.5rem",
          backgroundPosition: "0.5rem center",
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchInput;
```

This will create an input element with a search icon as its background, and the icon will be positioned inside the input at the center left of the input field.
You can adjust the position of the icon using the `background-position` property and you can adjust the size of the icon using the `background-size` property.

Comment: You could also use the ::before or ::after pseudo elements in the input element to insert the icon, and you can use the content CSS property to specify the icon as the content of the pseudo element.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the easyest way to use Icons in React Using Chakra Ui**

/* You can simply import chakra UI icons for this link */

```
 import { SearchIcon} from '@chakra-ui/icons'
 import { IconButton } from "@chakra-ui/button"
     /* Or use like this */
 return (
     <div>
         <IconButton aria-label='Search database' icon={<SearchIcon />} />
  </div>
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install **react-icons** in your project. You can do this using npm by running the following command in your terminal:

```
npm install react-icons
```

Once you have installed **react-icons**, you can import the **SearchIcon** component in your React component like this:

```
import { SearchIcon } from 'react-icons';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchIcon />
      <p>Click the icon to search</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example, we are importing the **SearchIcon** component from **react-icons** and using it within the **MyComponent** function. We are then rendering the icon along with some text in a div element.